# Asymptotic expansion of integral - issue with step in proof

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have been trying to read Asymptotic Analysis by J.D Murray. There is a page in the book, rather, a certain line in this page, that has confused me thoroughly.

What was said on the page before, is that $h$ is a function such that $h$, $h'$, $h''$ are all continuous on an interval $[0,T]$ and a larger interval containing $0$ as an interior point, and $h'(0) = 0, h''(0)<0$ so $h$ has a local maximum at $0$. We may restrict to a small interval $[0,\delta]$ if necessary.

So far it has been established, that we can write $h(t) - h(0) = \frac{1}{2}t^2h''(\theta)$ which is easy to see via noticing that we can write this difference as a Taylor series remainder.

[image]

The part on this page that confuses me is when we write $h(t) - h(0) = -s^2$, and now look for a first approximation for $t$ in terms of $s$, so we write $\frac{1}{2}t^2 h''(0)  + ... = -s^2$ , then in the next line in the page (2.27) we immediately get $t = (\frac{-2}{h''(0)})^{\frac{1}{2}} + \mathcal{O}(s^2)$. What is the $...$? and how do we go from this to (2.27)?

I put $...$ = $\mathcal{o}(t^2)$ which I think is true, but I still have no idea about this line and the line after it in general... Any insights would be very helpful to me , thanks!

Comment: The saddle point methods works by defining a new variable $s$ such that the exponential in the integrand becomes exactly $\exp(-s^2)$. This then gets multiplied by the Jacobian of the transform from $t$ to $s$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not sure if the saddle point method you are referring to is the same as Laplace's method, in any case I am aware we are trying to transform our integral to $exp(-s^2)$ , I believe this section of the book is detailing how we do this transform, and the derivation in the book, involves writing $t$ in terms of $s$. The issue I have is how the book goes from the line before (2.27) to (2.27).

Comment: That's a matter of inverting the series expansion. So, $t$ is now a function of $s$ and you can expand it in powers of $s$ and you have an explicit expression for the leading term.

Comment: Thank you, I see... I suppose my question was how we invert the series expansion to get that as a final expression.. sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious , we appear to be going from $\frac{t^2}{2}h''(0) + \mathcal{o}(t^2) = -s^2$ to (2.27)... it isn't clear to me how this is done

Comment: $s$ can be expressed as a power series in $t$ of the form $s = a t + b t^2 + +c t^3 + \cdots$. Then you have $s/a = t + b/a t^2 + c/a t^3+\cdots$. By taking the second, third etc. power of both sides, you can successively eliminate powers of $t$ in favor of powers of $s$

Comment: How do we know that $s$ can be expressed as a function of $t$? Aren't we assuming that $h(t)$ is invertible for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94672/discussion-between-aneesh-and-count-iblis).